# Directshow video render to two windows

Tags: directshow

I am using a directshow player which renders onto a panel using C++ Builder.  I wish to duplicate what is playing onto a second monitor.  Does directshow support any sort of events to say when a frame has been rendered by the renderer?

I am using the standard Microsoft player example which chooses the first available renderer which will work for the AVI file EVR, VRM9 this plays and renders fine. I would like to copy the rendered images as they update (50fps or 60fps max) and put them on a second screen which doesn't have all my other associated buttons and panels.

Comment: Have you found your way around? It seems **Infinite Pin Tee Filter** allows attaching multiple viewers. A quick GraphEdit test was successful.

Comment: Hello, I managed to get this working with Directshow by adding the infinite Tee and two presenters, each with their own windows.  Works good enough for my needs but probably not the correct way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure EVR or VMR9 to use windowless render mode and implement a [Custom Presenter for EVR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/how-to-write-an-evr-presenter) which will be responsible for rendering of each received frame (texture). You'll then be able to render this texture on separate windows.

Here is a link to implementing a [Custom Presenter for VMR9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/supplying-a-custom-allocator-presenter-for-vmr-9) as well, but IMO EVR is better to be used especially in Win 7 and higher.

Comment: thanks for the response.  Your answer is probably the better way to go, but a bit beyond my current level of confidence.  Thanks for the links, they will prove helpful in the future. For now I have managed to get it working by putting two renderer filters into the filter graph, one for each window.  This is working for me for now and easy to implement without having to add any filters to the system. I can look at better implementation down the track.